# Is it possible to unzip documents into a directory which is created on the fly in a single command?

Tags: command-line, unzip, mkdir

How can I achieve something like the following?

```
unzip ./zipped_docs.zip ./new_folder | mkdir ./new_folder
```

Or

```
mkdir ./new_folder | unzip ./zipped_docs.zip ./new_folder
```

I even tried

```
mkdir ./new_folder && unzip ./zipped_docs.zip ./new_folder
```

None of these have worked, but the idea is clear.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the `-d`-option in the `unzip`-command

```
mkdir new_folder && unzip zipped_docs.zip -d new_folder
```

From `man unzip`:

```
[-d exdir]
              An  optional  directory  to which to extract files.  By default,
              all files and subdirectories are recreated in the current direc‐
              tory;  the -d option allows extraction in an arbitrary directory
              (always assuming one has permission to write to the  directory).
```

Comment: Ah! I had in fact tried the `-d` option on one variation of my examples but clearly on the wrong one! Thanks.

Comment: Using history expansion you can shorten that and type the directory name only once: `mkdir new_folder && unzip zipped_docs.zip -d !#:1`

Answer (score 1):

I've found `file-roller` `-h` flag useful when the archive doesn't contain a single, top-level directory, but instead is a bunch of files and/or directories.  By using `file-roller -h`, a new directory matching the name of your archive will be created.

```
file-roller -h archive.zip
```

For example, `archive.zip` would be extracted into a newly created `archive` directory.  With a simple name, there would be collisions, but the idea is that the archive you're extracting would be relatively unique.

Instead of this directory being created automatically and based on the archive name, you can specify a directory using the `-e` flag.

```
file-roller -e /tmp/new_dir archive.zip
```

---

If the next step is to do this for a bunch of files in a directory, please take note of some common mistakes, specifically looping through files in a directory (ie: [`for f in dir/`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29))